When changing the background color of a div, the element inside it moves up
First, look at this:
at this SandBox:
Also, here's my code
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [change, setChange] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: change ? "grey" : "red",
            width: "40px",
            height: "40px",
            borderRadius: "40px",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            color: "black",
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            setChange(!change);
          }}
        >
          <p>15</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

I'm coding in react, and I was creating a seat-picker. Everytime I click on the seat, it changes its background color. Until there, everything fine, but when the background color changes, the text seems to move up. I put my finger on the screen and I could verify, text is really moving on the screen. What I don't get, is why when changing the background color, suddenly, the text inside the p, moves? Is it some sort of optical illusion? If it's, is there any workaround I could do? Anything else I could try?
I tried changing colors, and when the colors are close to each other, the text doesn't seem to move. But I wanted to freely use any color I want and not be affected by this possible illusion;

I can't see any reason this should be happening, it feels like it could be a quirk in webkit's anti-aliasing when layering certain colours... but there's not much you can do if that's the case.

Interestingly, I see the same up/down movement, however when I took screenshots and compared them zoomed in, the movement actually seems to go from left/right by about half a pixel.

Can't see what's wrong, works perfectly for me, (I did try your pointing technique)

I do not see any movement (Chrome/Edge Windows11). What device and what browser/OS are you using?

Using Brave. But I tried on Chromium/Firefox as well. I'm using Ubuntu. I also have tried on two different monitors.

Ow, just tried now, also happens on my Android phone.
